# Installation of Plasma Mobile on Nexus 5x failed "./fetch-demo.sh: 16: ./fetch-demo.sh: pushd: not found"

Tags: linux, android, kde, phone, flashing

I recently bought a used Nexus 5X that has already been rooted and had Lineage OS installed on it.  I wanted to convert it to Plasma Mobile but every time I try to flash it with the command

```
sudo ./pm-flash
```

I get an error message part way through.  I included the entire output if it helps but the error is found at the very end.

```
neon@neon:/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/pm-flashtool$ sudo ./pm-flash -p neon
+ CACHEDIR=cache
+ echo 'Waiting for device to be in the fastboot mode'
Waiting for device to be in the fastboot mode
+ fastboot getvar product
product: bullhead
finished. total time: 0.005s
++ fastboot getvar product
++ head -1
++ awk '-F: ' '{print $2}'
+ DEVICE_NAME=bullhead
+ confirm 'Connected device is bullhead, is that correct? [y/N]'
+ read -r -p 'Connected device is bullhead, is that correct? [y/N] ' response
Connected device is bullhead, is that correct? [y/N] y
+ case $response in
+ true
+ PLATFORM=neon
+ echo 'Continuing ...'
Continuing ...
+ getopts cp: opt
+ case $opt in
+ PLATFORM=neon
+ getopts cp: opt
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ download bullhead neon
+ '[' 2 -eq 0 ']'
+ mkdir -p cache/
+ pushd cache/
/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/pm-flashtool/cache /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/pm-flashtool
+ echo 'Downloading latest rootfs ... '
Downloading latest rootfs ... 
+ '[' neon == neon ']'
++ curl https://images.plasma-mobile.org/rootfs_stamp
+ ROOTFS_VERSION=20190208-135835
+ wget -c https://images.plasma-mobile.org/rootfs/pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.tar.gz -P rootfs
--2019-02-12 01:54:53--  https://images.plasma-mobile.org/rootfs/pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.tar.gz
Resolving images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)... 207.154.251.179
Connecting to images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)|207.154.251.179|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 560234962 (534M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘rootfs/pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.tar.gz’

pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.ta 100%[==============================================>] 534.28M   209KB/s    in 21m 12s 

2019-02-12 02:16:06 (430 KB/s) - ‘rootfs/pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.tar.gz’ saved [560234962/560234962]

+ ln -sf rootfs/pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.tar.gz pm-rootfs-latest.tar.gz
+ '[' neon == arch ']'
+ '[' neon == edge ']'
+ echo '[done]'
[done]
+ echo 'Downloading the latest boot, recovery, and system images  ... '
Downloading the latest boot, recovery, and system images  ... 
++ curl https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/halium_stamp
+ HALIUM_VERSION=20180209-134208
+ wget -c https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/recovery.img -P bullhead
--2019-02-12 02:16:07--  https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/recovery.img
Resolving images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)... 207.154.251.179
Connecting to images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)|207.154.251.179|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 16827692 (16M)
Saving to: ‘bullhead/recovery.img’

recovery.img                 100%[==============================================>]  16.05M  1.03MB/s    in 21s     

2019-02-12 02:16:30 (771 KB/s) - ‘bullhead/recovery.img’ saved [16827692/16827692]

+ wget -c https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/20180209-134208/system.img -P bullhead/20180209-134208
--2019-02-12 02:16:30--  https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/20180209-134208/system.img
Resolving images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)... 207.154.251.179
Connecting to images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)|207.154.251.179|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 195715072 (187M)
Saving to: ‘bullhead/20180209-134208/system.img’

system.img                   100%[==============================================>] 186.65M  1.19MB/s    in 2m 48s  

2019-02-12 02:19:19 (1.11 MB/s) - ‘bullhead/20180209-134208/system.img’ saved [195715072/195715072]

+ wget -c https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/20180209-134208/boot.img -P bullhead/20180209-134208
--2019-02-12 02:19:19--  https://images.plasma-mobile.org/halium/bullhead/20180209-134208/boot.img
Resolving images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)... 207.154.251.179
Connecting to images.plasma-mobile.org (images.plasma-mobile.org)|207.154.251.179|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11956224 (11M)
Saving to: ‘bullhead/20180209-134208/boot.img’

boot.img                     100%[==============================================>]  11.40M  1.06MB/s    in 13s     

2019-02-12 02:19:32 (927 KB/s) - ‘bullhead/20180209-134208/boot.img’ saved [11956224/11956224]

+ rm -f bullhead/latest
+ ln -sf 20180209-134208 bullhead/latest
+ echo '[done]'
[done]
+ popd
/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/pm-flashtool
+ flash-phone bullhead
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo -n 'Flashing recovery image ... '
Flashing recovery image ... + fastboot flash recovery cache/bullhead/recovery.img
+ echo -n '[done]'
[done]+ fastboot boot cache/bullhead/recovery.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.716s]
booting...
OKAY [  0.551s]
finished. total time: 1.267s
+ wait_for_device
++ adb shell echo 1
+ test -z 'adb server version (40) doesn'\''t match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *'
+ echo

++ readlink -f cache/pm-rootfs-latest.tar.gz
+ ./rootstock-touch-install /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/pmflashtool/cache/rootfs/pm-rootfs-20190208-135835.tar.gz cache/bullhead/latest/system.img cache/bullhead/latest/boot.img
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p40 on /cache failed: Device or resource busy
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p45 on /data failed: Device or resource busy
transfering rootfs tarball ... [done]
preparing system-image on device ... [done]
unpacking rootfs tarball to system-image ... [done]
adding android system image to installation ... [done]
Setting up default password for phablet user to 1234 ... [done]
Cloning into 'fetch-demo-data'...
remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 12 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
--2019-02-12 02:23:03--  http://acbf.info/download?id=0016
Resolving acbf.info (acbf.info)... 5.10.124.141
Connecting to acbf.info (acbf.info)|5.10.124.141|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘OUTPUT/Documents/Pepper___Carrot___Vol__1.cbz’

OUTPUT/Documents/Pepper___Ca     [                                    <=>        ]  21.77M   943KB/s    in 27s     

2019-02-12 02:23:32 (835 KB/s) - ‘OUTPUT/Documents/Pepper___Carrot___Vol__1.cbz’ saved [22831062]

--2019-02-12 02:23:32--  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.pdf
Resolving www.gnu.org (www.gnu.org)... 209.51.188.148, 2001:470:142:3::a
Connecting to www.gnu.org (www.gnu.org)|209.51.188.148|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104908 (102K) [application/pdf]
Saving to: ‘OUTPUT/Documents/quick-guide-gplv3.pdf’

quick-guide-gplv3.pdf        100%[==============================================>] 102.45K   520KB/s    in 0.2s    

2019-02-12 02:23:33 (520 KB/s) - ‘OUTPUT/Documents/quick-guide-gplv3.pdf’ saved [104908/104908]

./fetch-demo.sh: 16: ./fetch-demo.sh: pushd: not found
```

If someone could help find out why it snags at the last line I would appreciate it.

(I am running Linux Mint 18 Xfce if that helps.)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Note: this was originally posted by the OP as an edit to the question).</sup>

I emailed plasma mobile and I got the answer:

The problem is that `/bin/sh` used by the `fetch-demo.sh` script links to `/bin/dash` on Debian and derivatives like Linux Mint. And since dash doesn't support the pushd support, the script crashes.

To fix this, the `fetch-demo.sh` script should run in Bash. I just submitted a patch to fix this by default: https://github.com/plasma-phone-packaging/pm-flashtool/pull/36

If you don't want to wait until it is accepted, edit the first line of `fetch-demo.sh` from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: `pushd` is not required by POSIX so any implementation of `sh` may not support it. The problem is neither with Debian/Mint nor with `dash`. It's them using `pushd` which is not portable.